# Node js traffic balancing

Tags: node.js, load-balancing

I need to scale my node.js app on multiple server locations. Since it is a real time multiplayer game, users must connect to a server with the least latency. How can I let the players choose the server/region they want to connect to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply deploy multiple versions of the server in different regions, and allow users to select which server/region they want to play on. This is assuming there's no cross-talk among different servers/regions, which is mostly the case for games.

Treat the servers in each server/region as separate applications. For each server/region, you will have a different IP with which you access it.

Note that you will also have to load-balance within each server/region. You can do this via servers such as nginx, or by using load-balancing capabilities offered by cloud computing suites, such as Google App Engine, Amazon Web Services, etc.